# The zero vector in the vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a trivial question, If $V$ is the vector space on a field $F$, and $\operatorname{dim}_F V=n$. Is the zero vector of $V$, the vector whose elements is the zero of $F$ ?

That’s mean, if $a\in F$ is the zero of $F$, then $0_v=(a,...,a)$ (n times) ?

Sorry I don’t speak English well.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you write vectors in components so $n$ components, then zero vector has all components zero.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you so much.

Comment: @MorganRodgers thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in general.

> Is the zero vector of $V$, the vector whose elements is the zero of
>   $F$ ?

Consider the vector space $V$ of functions from a set to a field  $F$. Then the zero vector of $V$ is the **function** which assigns to each element of the set to the scalar $0$ in $F$.

> That’s mean, if $a\in F$ is the zero of $F$, then $0_v=(a,...,a)$ (n
>   times)

Consider a subspace $W$ of vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose the dimension of $W$ is $2$. Then the zero vector of $W$ is still  $(0,0,0)$,not $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.